# Call start from another class without a primaryStage

Tags: javafx

I want to make an application, I have a home scene and I have a menubox which I can add to the scene in all classes. Now I want to add an eventhandler in that menubox to switch to the home scene. I need a primaryStage to call home.start(Stage stage). Which doesn't exist in the menubox class. I think I need to get the primaryStage from the home class, and pass it to home.start(primaryStage). I have no idea how to do that.

Here is my code so far:

The home class:

```
package login;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Home {

//mysql connectie
Mysql mysql = new Mysql();

//private mqsql
private final String USERNAME = mysql.getUsername();
private final String PASSWORD = mysql.getPassword();
private final String CONN_STRING = mysql.getUrlmysql();


public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    GebruikerAanmaken gebruikerAanmaken = new GebruikerAanmaken();
    Login log = new Login();
    GebruikerAanpassen gebruikerAanpassen = new GebruikerAanpassen();
    GevKofferReg gevKofferReg = new GevKofferReg();

    VerlKofferReg verlKofferReg = new VerlKofferReg();



    // deze vijf regels om een homeknop aan te roepen
    MenuB menuB = new MenuB();
    MenuBar menuBar = menuB.createMenuB();        
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
    root.setTop(menuBar);



    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    // deze regel moet ook aangemaakt worden voor de homeknop
    root.setCenter(grid);

    Button buttonGebruikerAanmaken = new Button("Gebruiker aanmaken");
    Button buttonSignIn = new Button("Sign in");
    Button buttonGebruikerAanpassen = new Button("Gebruiker aanpassen");
    Button buttonGevondenKofferRegistreren = new Button("Gevonden bagage registreren");
    Button buttonVerlKofferReg = new Button("Verloren bagage registreren");

    if(Login.rol.equals("admin")){
        root.getChildren().add(buttonGebruikerAanmaken);
        grid.add(buttonGebruikerAanmaken, 0, 6);
        root.getChildren().add(buttonGebruikerAanpassen);
        grid.add(buttonGebruikerAanpassen, 4, 6);
    }else{
        root.getChildren().add(buttonSignIn);
        grid.add(buttonSignIn, 4, 6);
        grid.add(buttonGevondenKofferRegistreren, 3,6);

    }

    buttonGebruikerAanpassen.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        gebruikerAanpassen.star(primaryStage);
    });

    buttonSignIn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        log.start(primaryStage);
    });

    buttonGebruikerAanmaken.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        gebruikerAanmaken.start(primaryStage);
    });

    buttonGevondenKofferRegistreren.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        gevKofferReg.start(primaryStage);
    });

    buttonVerlKofferReg.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        verlKofferReg.start(primaryStage);
    });


    // deze aanpassen van grid naar root..
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 920);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Home");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

and the menubar class:

```
package login;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class MenuB {

public MenuBar createMenuB(){

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

// File menu - new, save, exit
Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
MenuItem newMenuItem = new MenuItem("New");
MenuItem saveMenuItem = new MenuItem("Save");
MenuItem homeMenuItem = new MenuItem("Home");
homeMenuItem.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
//Here is where i want to go to the home scene

});

fileMenu.getItems().addAll(newMenuItem, saveMenuItem,
    new SeparatorMenuItem(), homeMenuItem);

Menu webMenu = new Menu("Web");
CheckMenuItem htmlMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("HTML");
htmlMenuItem.setSelected(true);
webMenu.getItems().add(htmlMenuItem);

CheckMenuItem cssMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("CSS");
cssMenuItem.setSelected(true);
webMenu.getItems().add(cssMenuItem);

Menu sqlMenu = new Menu("SQL");
ToggleGroup tGroup = new ToggleGroup();
RadioMenuItem mysqlItem = new RadioMenuItem("MySQL");
mysqlItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);

RadioMenuItem oracleItem = new RadioMenuItem("Oracle");
oracleItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);
oracleItem.setSelected(true);

sqlMenu.getItems().addAll(mysqlItem, oracleItem,
    new SeparatorMenuItem());

Menu tutorialManeu = new Menu("Tutorial");
tutorialManeu.getItems().addAll(
    new CheckMenuItem("Java"),
    new CheckMenuItem("JavaFX"),
    new CheckMenuItem("Swing"));

sqlMenu.getItems().add(tutorialManeu);

menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, webMenu, sqlMenu);

return menuBar;

}

}
```

I know the coding is not the best, but I'm new to programming and this is for a 
school assignment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do a search?

Comment: Yeah, couldn't find an answer anywhere, can you give me a link to an answer?

Comment: I didn't search, but this seems like a question that has been asked before. I could be wrong.

Comment: I've been searching for a long time now and couldn't find an answer anywhere :(

Comment: When you `createMenuB()` why dont you pass it the `primaryStage` there?

Comment: Wow, that's it. So simpel thanks man!